# gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme won't install due to unmet dependencies

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I have gnome-tweak-tool install and use it regulary. I cannot however install the gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme to change the shell.

I already have the ppa but when it put

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme

into the terminal i get this output.

```
dvorak@dvorak-g51vx:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
[sudo] password for dvorak:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common
but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone elaborate on what I am doing wrong? I have tried to both install and remove both the unmet dependencies with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem. gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme is 3.2 whereas the shell is 3.4. Shell extensions seem to be handled by installing from https://extensions.gnome.org/ rather than yourself via package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Try ;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try installing `gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme` again

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

If you get any error message with those first 3 commands, post back or use pastebin

Answer (score 1):

Installing from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/ ended up working for me. Had the exact same error msg.

Notes
ubuntu precise -> gnome3 shell
64bit